# How to Apply color to Weekends(saturdays & sundays) and next or previous months dates in datetimepicker using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datetimepicker

I have the below code for datetime picker,
which is running well, but i need to fill the colors for weekends(saturdays & sundays) and
next or previous months dates too.

Please help to do that.
below is runnable code, please provide code to do that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker(
    {
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
    }
);
});
</script>
<style>
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class called `.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .weekend`. Change that like below.

```css
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .weekend {
  color: red;
  /*Apply your color*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how to change the colors of previous month and next month dates in current month.

Comment: for example: when we open month December,  we can see previous month dates: 29 &30               and  next month dates: 1 & 2 etc ,    now can we make those dates color to light color.